# Jenkins pipeline script to publish into Jfrogartifactory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, artifactory

I am trying to write a pipeline script to publish `*.war/*.jar`  file to JFrogArtifactory. I don't find any syntax for the same.

Anyone can help me out on the same.

please help me with a sample script.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You may or may not find specific syntax for Artifactory upload but if you can do it from command line, then it can be done from Jenkins as well. Depending on your OS, you just need to search StackOverflow or Google on how to run `bat` or `sh` commands in Jenkins

Comment: Are you building using maven, ant, or ... ? Should be a deploy command (plus configuration). Lots of data googling 'jenkins deploy artifactory".

Answer (score 0):

JFrog has a [dedicated GitHub repository](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples) with many examples for such cases.

There are [Jenkins Pipelines](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples) examples there.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must install Artifactory Plugin and config it in Jenkins server. 
Refer: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuring+Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in 
And then try add below script to Jenkinsfile:

```
script {
    def server = Artifactory.server '<artifactory id>'
    def uploadSpec = '''{
        "files": [{
        "pattern": "<name of war or jar file>",
        "target": "<artifactory repo>/path-to/war-or-jar/file/in-Artifactory"
        }]
    }'''
    server.upload(uploadSpec) 
}
```

Don't forget replace `<artifactory id>` `<name of war or jar file>` and `<artifactory repo>/path-to/war-or-jar/file/in-Artifactory`

More information: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax

Answer (score 0):

The scripted pipeline syntax for deploying war files to JFrog artifactory is :

```
    env.ARTIFACTORY = 'True'
    if(env.ARTIFACTORY == 'True')
    {
        stage('Deploying to Artifactory')
        {
            FAILED_STAGE = env.STAGE_NAME
            bat 'mvn deploy'
        }
    }
```

Note :

1.) 'bat' command is for Windows batch file. If you're using Linux, replace 'bat' with 'sh'

2.) env.ARTIFACTORY is used to give you control over whether or not you want to execute this particular stage in your pipeline job. if you don't want this stage to execute, simply set env.ARTIFACTORY = 'False'

3.) Also note, you've to configure JFrog in : Manage Jenkins -> Configure system -> JFrog Platform Instances

4.) Include JFrog in your pom.xml file under distributionManagement tag.